# Optimizing deleting million rows in a SQL databse

Tags: jdbc, query-optimization

Imagine a situation when you have a table with 2 million rows and you wanted to delete a million rows. These rows are not bunched together. I might want to delete row1, and then row5, and then may be row7. But I want to deletes rows that may have age < 23 What is the best way to go about deleting these rows?

Comment: How do you choose which rows to delete?

Comment: You have the information to delete the rows in the arrayList. The rest is up to you on how to use that information.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to delete them in batches. This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925471/how-can-i-delete-expired-data-from-a-huge-table-without-having-the-log-file-grow) provides some interesting answers.